# Async in getting files in folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in Node.js . All I did in here is get file list in folder... Everything in Node.js seem to async but my function I want it in synchronous way.
So, I do as follow.

```
function getFiles() {
var file = [];
var walker = walk.walk('./files');

walker.on('file', function (root, stat, next) {
    file.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
})

walker.on('end', function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
})

return file;}
```

It worked as I expected :

```
["./files/1.mp3","./files/2.mp3","./files/3.mp3","./files/4.mp3","./files/5.mp3","./files/6.mp3","./files/7.mp3","./files/8.mp3"]
```

but when I assigned that function to variable

```
var list = getFiles();
 response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'application/json'});
response.end(JSON.stringify(list));
```

It always returned **nothing**, I think that `getFiles()` run in another thread so  can not receive value of data. Thank for your reading.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: And, not; that is fully single-threaded, but asynchronous.  You need to make your function async too.

Comment: is it impossible if I put 'response.end(data)' in 'walker.on('end', function (){...}'?

Comment: That will work, since you'll only use the result after it's finished.

Comment: It will work if I set'list' as Global variable, but I have to request in second times. The uers dont like it :(

Comment: That's why you need a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can shed some light on the behavior you are experiencing by outlining the flow of the application as it is run:

```
call to getFiles
  declare files array and walker
  bind walker event "file" and "end" to callbacks
  return files array

walker file event fires
walker end event fires
```

as you can see the events are firing out of band with the method call. To deal with this the common node.js approach is to setup your code something like the following:

```
function getFiles(callback) {
  var file = [];
  var walker = walk.walk('./files');

  walker.on('file', function (root, stat, next) {
    file.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
  })

  walker.on('end', function () {
    callback(file);
  })
}
```

now when you go to execute this method you would do something like this:

```
getFiles(function(list){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'application/json'});
  response.end(JSON.stringify(list));
});
```

obviously this is a little unsightly since the controller now has to create a callback scenario and the getFiles method need to execute that callback in course. Another approach is to use the Promises concept, which I will leave to the discovery of the reader with the following link: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Could you comment on why this is unsightly?  It is, after all, the primary method and expected.

Comment: @Paul I have to admit that in this limited scenario there is very little that is unslightly about it, except for the creation of an anonymous function in line, it is fine. There are many, myself included, who have seen this paradigm fall down in scenarios where parallel execution or standard flow control are needed and this type of execution can become unsightly when multiple asynchronous operations need to be run in serial. Promises represent a slightly more procedural aesthetic to a more complex solution.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks.  I understand that there is an async.js library that might be of use, too, with helpers for various paradigms inside.  Not sure how that compares with promises, but I'll leave that question for another day.

Answer (score 1):

- Async functions return before they are ready
- You can't return data thats not there in your own code
- Async functions often take a callback argument that is executed when they are ready
- You own code could ask for its own callbacks

`

```
function getFiles(callBack) {
var file = [];
var walker = walk.walk('./files');

walker.on('file', function (root, stat, next) {
    file.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
})

walker.on('end', function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
    callBack(file);
})

}

// assuming server environment, express, connect, etc...

app.get('/list', function(req, res){
      getFiles(function(D){ res.json(D) });
});
```

`